# HTML tooltip needed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please help me with my project, I need to have a tooltip in my html, my question is, how to add a tooltip into an existing icon or a picture ?

Sorry for my bad english, here's my code (HTML and CSS):

```css
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
Project:  Celery
Version:  1.2
Last change:
Assigned to:
Primary use:
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/



/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ FONT ]*/

@font-face {
  font-family: PlayfairDisplay-Regular;
  src: url('../fonts/PlayfairDisplay/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: PlayfairDisplay-BlackItalic;
  src: url('../fonts/PlayfairDisplay/PlayfairDisplay-BlackItalic.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  src: url('../fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  src: url('../fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf');
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ RS PLUGIN ]*/
/*---------------------------------------------*/
.container {max-width: 1200px;}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Form ]*/
.contact100-form {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Input ]*/

.wrap-input100 {
  width: 650px;
  max-width: calc(100% + 110px);
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 80px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .wrap-input100 {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.input100 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 80px 0 172px;
  background-color: #ffe151;

  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.input100:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .input100 {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Alert validate ]*/

.validate-input {
  position: relative;
}

.alert-validate::before {
  content: attr(data-validate);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c80000;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 4px 25px 4px 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 72px;
  pointer-events: none;

  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.alert-validate::after {
  content: "\f071";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 78px;
}

.alert-validate:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .alert-validate::before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Simple slide100 ]*/
.simpleslide100-parent {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.simpleslide100 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.simpleslide100-item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}



/*==================================================================
    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
==================================================================*/

/*==================================================================
[ Color ]*/
.cl0 {color: #fff;}
.cl1 {color: #333;}




/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ S-Text 0 - 15 ]*/

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.s2-txt1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.2;
}



/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ M-Text 16 - 25 ]*/

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.m2-txt1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.m2-txt2 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}



/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ L-Text >= 26 ]*/
.l1-txt1 {
  font-family: PlayfairDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*==================================================================
   SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE SHAPE
==================================================================*/
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Size ]*/
.size1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.size2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.size3 {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.size4 {
  width: 172px;
  height: 80px;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Width ]*/
.wsize1 {
  width: 37%;
}

.wsize2 {
  width: 63%;
}

.wsize3 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Height ]*/




/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Background ]*/
.bg0 {background-color: #fff;}

.bg-img1 {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}




/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Border ]*/
.bor1 {
  border-left: 5px solid #333;
}




/*==================================================================
   WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE WHERE
==================================================================*/




/*==================================================================
 HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW HOW
==================================================================*/
.placeholder0::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #666;}
.placeholder0:-moz-placeholder { color: #666;}
.placeholder0::-moz-placeholder { color: #666;}
.placeholder0:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #666;}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
.overlay1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.wrappic1 {
  display: block;
}

.wrappic1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.how-btn1 {
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.how-btn1:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #fff;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.how-social {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.how-social:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Pseudo ]*/

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Focus ]*/
.focus-in0:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.focus-in0:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.focus-in0:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
.focus-in0:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Hover ]*/
.hov-cl0:hover {color: #fff;}
.hov-bg0:hover {background-color: #fff;}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.hov1:hover i {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
  -o-transform: translateX(10px);
  transform: translateX(10px);
}






/*==================================================================
  RESPONSIVE RESPONSIVE RESPONSIVE RESPONSIVE RESPONSIVE RESPONSIVE
==================================================================*/


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ XL ]*/
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .m-0-xl {margin: 0;}
  .m-lr-0-xl {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}
  .m-lr-15-xl {margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;}
  .m-l-0-xl {margin-left: 0;}
  .m-r-0-xl {margin-right: 0;}
  .m-l-15-xl {margin-left: 15px;}
  .m-r-15-xl {margin-right: 15px;}

  .p-0-xl {padding: 0;}
  .p-lr-0-xl {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
  .p-lr-15-xl {padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;}
  .p-l-0-xl {padding-left: 0;}
  .p-r-0-xl {padding-right: 0;}
  .p-l-15-xl {padding-left: 15px;}
  .p-r-15-xl {padding-right: 15px;}

  .w-full-xl {width: 100%;}

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon1 {
    width: 60%;
  }

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon2 {
    width: 40%;
  }

}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ LG ]*/
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .dis-none-lg {display: none;}
  .m-0-lg {margin: 0;}
  .m-lr-0-lg {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}
  .m-lr-15-lg {margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;}
  .m-l-0-lg {margin-left: 0;}
  .m-r-0-lg {margin-right: 0;}
  .m-l-15-lg {margin-left: 15px;}
  .m-r-15-lg {margin-right: 15px;}

  .p-0-lg {padding: 0;}
  .p-lr-0-lg {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
  .p-lr-15-lg {padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;}
  .p-l-0-lg {padding-left: 0;}
  .p-r-0-lg{padding-right: 0;}
  .p-l-15-lg {padding-left: 15px;}
  .p-r-15-lg {padding-right: 15px;}

  .w-full-lg {width: 100%;}

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }


}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ MD ]*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .m-0-md {margin: 0;}
  .m-lr-0-md {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}
  .m-lr-15-md {margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;}
  .m-l-0-md {margin-left: 0;}
  .m-r-0-md {margin-right: 0;}
  .m-l-15-md {margin-left: 15px;}
  .m-r-15-md {margin-right: 15px;}

  .p-0-md {padding: 0;}
  .p-lr-0-md {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
  .p-lr-15-md {padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;}
  .p-l-0-md {padding-left: 0;}
  .p-r-0-md{padding-right: 0;}
  .p-l-15-md {padding-left: 15px;}
  .p-r-15-md {padding-right: 15px;}

  .w-full-md {width: 100%;}
  /*---------------------------------------------*/

}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ SM ]*/
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .dis-none-sm {display: none;}
  .m-0-sm {margin: 0;}
  .m-lr-0-sm {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}
  .m-lr-15-sm {margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;}
  .m-l-0-sm {margin-left: 0;}
  .m-r-0-sm {margin-right: 0;}
  .m-l-15-sm {margin-left: 15px;}
  .m-r-15-sm {margin-right: 15px;}

  .p-0-sm {padding: 0;}
  .p-lr-0-sm {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
  .p-lr-15-sm {padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;}
  .p-l-0-sm {padding-left: 0;}
  .p-r-0-sm{padding-right: 0;}
  .p-l-15-sm {padding-left: 15px;}
  .p-r-15-sm {padding-right: 15px;}

  .w-full-sm {width: 100%;}

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon3 {
    font-size: 60px;
  }

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon4 {
    width: 5px;
  }

  .respon4 span {
    display: none;
  }

  /*---------------------------------------------*/
  .respon5 {
    width: 60px;
  }

}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ SSM ]*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .m-0-ssm {margin: 0;}
  .m-lr-0-ssm {margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}
  .m-lr-15-ssm {margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;}
  .m-l-0-ssm {margin-left: 0;}
  .m-r-0-ssm {margin-right: 0;}
  .m-l-15-ssm {margin-left: 15px;}
  .m-r-15-ssm {margin-right: 15px;}

  .p-0-ssm {padding: 0;}
  .p-lr-0-ssm {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
  .p-lr-15-ssm {padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;}
  .p-l-0-ssm {padding-left: 0;}
  .p-r-0-ssm{padding-right: 0;}
  .p-l-15-ssm {padding-left: 15px;}
  .p-r-15-ssm {padding-right: 15px;}

  .w-full-ssm {width: 100%;}
  /*---------------------------------------------*/

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>AN Newsletter | Thank you</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>



    <div class="flex-w flex-str size1 overlay1">
        <div class="flex-w flex-col-sb wsize1 bg0 p-l-70 p-t-37 p-b-52 p-r-50 respon1">
            <div class="wrappic1">
                <a href="../main/index.html">
                    <img src="images/icons/logo.png" alt="IMG">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="w-full p-t-100 p-b-90 p-l-48 p-l-0-md">

                <h3 class="l1-txt1 p-b-34 respon3">
                    Thank you
                </h3>

                <p class="m2-txt1 p-b-46">
                    Your request has been received.
                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="flex-w flex-m">
                <span class="m2-txt2 p-r-40">
                    Navigation
                </span>

                <a href="../main/index.html" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="../main/contact.html" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="wsize2 bg-img1 respon2" style="background-image: url('images/bg01.jpg');">
        </div>
    </div>





<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me by adding the tooltip syntax, any help would be appreciated

The tooltip is for this part in HTML :

```
            <div class="flex-w flex-m">
                <span class="m2-txt2 p-r-40">
                    Navigation
                </span>

                <a href="../main/index.html" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="../main/contact.html" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                </a>

            </div>
```

Comment: Please help me by adding the tooltip syntax in my code above, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check the documentation here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Comment: Use `title="tooltip"` - `<img src=".." title="image" alt="img"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `title` to be your tooltip message.

No need to do this CSS or anything if you want it to simple tooltip message.

This will appear once your hover (place your mouse over it) over the Navigation it will show 'I am tooltip'

You can do this with almost every HTML element. Just add you own message so the user will see it once the user hover over it.

You can same  thing with `img` as well.

Learn more about **custom CSS tooltips** here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Run snippet below to see it working.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="flex-w flex-m">
  <span class="m2-txt2 p-r-40" title="I am tooltip">
                    Navigation
                </span>

  <a href="../main/index.html" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
    <i class="fa fa-home" title="I am tooltip"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="../main/contact.html" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
    <i class="fa fa-phone" title="I am tooltip"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-15 m-b-5 m-t-5">
    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there anyway to control the title delay ?, the title appears really slow, if you have tips on how to control the delay please share it to me, thanks.

Comment: @AudyNaufal Glad that’s I helped you. HTML title will appear like that with a bit of a second delay. If you want no delay at all then I would recommend using custom tool tips by doing your own CSS. I have added the link for that above in how you can do that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Next time try to provide a link with your code hosted on codepen/jsfiddle for a cleaner and easier reading or be more precise with your question. What I understood from your question is that you want a hovering text option for your image/content. If I didn't understand that please correct me. One way for you to do it is like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
  <img src= "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" title="example for hover tooltip" alt="simple image" width="300">

</body>
</html>
```